# Can't change case Owner in Aura using <lightning:recordEditForm>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

Is there any way to change Owner of case using Lightning record edit form?

I Want to use `OwnerId` Field only. When I use

```
<lightning:inputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="OwnerId" autocomplete="off"/>
```

it comes fixed in form and can't be changed.

Comment: use a quick action to change the owner of the case.

Comment: chatter is enabled on case ,so quick action launched component  comes inside chatter

Comment: and need component because of some other requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OwnerId` is not supported by [`lightning:inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation).

> The Owner, CreatedBy, and LastModifiedBy fields are not supported for lookups.

You will need to utilize other approach here to be able to update this field.